# Different modifiers to trigger different commands on WPF input bindings

Tags: wpf, xaml, inputbinding

I've run into trouble trying to work out how to trigger different commands for different modifier keys on the same mouse action in WPF. I've developed a set of graph classes which I am trying to allow the user to select points in. The graph object maintains a list of selected points and the commands when passed a point as a parameter should either select only the point which was given (SelectPointCommand) or add the point to the current selection (AddPointToSelectionCommand).

I'm aware that I could just check Keyboard.Modifiers in the code the runs when the command is executed however I would prefer to provide the functionality at a fairly high level, rather than restricting it to certain modifier keys in the graph object itself, so that the same functionality can easily be triggered by other methods eg. clicking a button.

I would have thought that the following XAML would work (border is just a simplification of the actual data template there are no problems detecting the mouse gesture)

```
<Border DataContext="{Binding Point}">
    <Border.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="Ctrl+LeftClick" Command="{Binding Line.Graph.AddPointToSelectionCommand, Mode=Onetime}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        <MouseBinding Gesture="Shift+LeftClick" Command="{Binding Line.Graph.AddPointToSelectionCommand, Mode=Onetime}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding Line.Graph.SelectPointCommand, Mode=Onetime}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    </Border.InputBindings>
</Border>
```

With this XAML the MouseBinding for LeftClick is triggered most of the time, regardless of which modifier keys are held down. Ctrl+LeftClick or Shift+LeftClick seem to trigger occasionally but not with any particular pattern. I've tried defining the LeftClick mousebinding at a higher level (and at a lower level) under the assumption that the LeftClick MouseBinding would only trigger if the more specific bindings with modifiers didn't but it doesn't seem to work that way.

In a more general sense is it actually possible to bind the same mouse action with different modifier keys to different commands? I would have thought more specific bindings or ones which were defined earlier in the XAML would be triggered instead of broader/later defined ones.